# How to write to csv file in seperate columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write a code which asks a user for a username and password and then stores these into a csv file in 2 seperate columns. I have tried lots of different methods but cannot seem to do it :/

```
username = input ("What is your first name (or username)? ")
 username = (username[0:3])
 birthyear = input ("What year were you born? ")
 birthyear = (birthyear[2:4])
 print (("Your username is ") + (username) + (birthyear))
 login = (username) + (birthyear)
 newpassword = input ("Please create a password ")
 with open ("scores.csv", "a") as scoreFile:
     scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile)
     scoreFileWriter.writerow(username + "," + newpassword+"\n")
     scoreFile.close()
```

This is one way I've tried but it writes every single letter in a different column like this:

b o b , p a s s w o r d

Instead of this:

bob, password

Thanks in advance if you can offer any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a delimiter of ','. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

`scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile, delimiter=',')`

Also, storying passwords in plain-text is Very Bad Practice (TM).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in this line you're doing the comma yourself, that is what the csv writer will do for your (as @Pipupnipup said, specify a delimeter)

You should just pass writerow a list and let it handle the newline and comma:

```
scoreFileWriter.writerow([username, newpassword])
```

And to iterate: Storing passwords in plain-text is Very Bad Practice (TM).

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
username = input ("What is your first name (or username)? ")
 username = (username[0:3])
 birthyear = input ("What year were you born? ")
 birthyear = (birthyear[2:4])
 print (("Your username is ") + (username) + (birthyear))
 login = (username) + (birthyear)
 newpassword = input ("Please create a password ")
 with open ("scores.csv", "a") as scoreFile:
     scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile, delimiter=',')
     scoreFileWriter.writerow([login, newpassword])
     scoreFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your stated problem .writerow() requires a sequence ('', (), []).
As you were passing strings not a sequence writerow() iterates over each letter in your string and each letter is written to a separate cell in the CSV. By giving [username, newpassword] you provide a sequence.

Also, note that you are passing the original Username, as the entered string, not the concatenation of username + birthyear which you return to the user as their username.